# To change the color of the event after processing

Tags: fullcalendar

To change the color of the calendar after processing.
Instead of changing the color of the initial state, we want to change the color of certain events later.

```
function change_color(event_id){
.....
change color event
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
             .......
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`eventRender`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback to bind a click function or whatever you want to the event elements. In [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kgwbdg) I have added a click function that when an event is clicked it will change the color to green with css. You can also access the event properties to do something like `event.color = 'green'`, which will not update on the calendar but could be useful for updating the event in the database.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    element.bind('click', function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
i will try.